# FUNCTION database.AddDays does not exist

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, sql-function

I'm trying to use dbfunction from EF6 on database MySQL but I get the follow exception "FUNCTION database.DiffDays does not exist".

I used this code:

```
var aux = bd.Atos.Where(w => w.IdAtivo == 1 && w.IdUtilizador == idUtilizador && DbFunctions.DiffDays(DbFunctions.AddDays(w.Data, w.NumDias).Value, DateTime.Now).Value < numeroDias)
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: *FUNCTION database.AddDays does not exist* *I get the follow exception "FUNCTION database.DiffDays does not exist".* What is the actual problem? Aside from the fact that you're using MySQL.

Comment: You say the problem is because MySQL? It don't support the dbfunctions?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by creating the respective functions in MySQL. thx for the help

Comment: How do you call this function? DbFunctions is not recognized in my code

Comment: You need refer System.Data.Entity

Comment: @fmalh3iro Can you please explain how you solved this issue?

Comment: I've created in the database a function named DiffDays with two parameters of type Date