# Use DbFunctions to return the dateTime with mins included

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following code, which truncates the time:

```
// does this already exist? 
var seekScan = (from s in aDb.Item_Scan_Event
                where s.item_detail_id == th_piece_id &&
                      s.scan_type == scantype &&
                      DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.scan_datetime) == dt_scan.s.ScanDatetime.Date
                select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

What I need instead is to have it compare the dateTime including the HH:mm

I have tried using something simple like a string comparison but you can't do that inside of a Linq-to-Entities:

```
var seekScan = (from s in aDb.Item_Scan_Event
                where s.item_detail_id == th_piece_id &&
                      s.scan_type == scantype &&
                      s.scan_datetime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") == dt_scan.s.ScanDatetime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
                select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

The error I get is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Can you not define a local variable with the dates without the seconds and milliseconds and use those in your query?

Comment: It is the portion on the left side of the compare (the database part) that is causing the issue.  I am not sure how to do what you suggest?

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting exactly, I'm sorry.
I get the concept, but I cannot figure out a way to cod that?

Comment: Yeah my bad, did not think far enough :/

Comment: I think it will have to do with CreateTime or something....still working on it.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235304/how-to-use-canonical-functions-in-entity-framework-and-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying [Joe Ruder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58935474/3759822) and using `DbFunctions` class :

```cs
var seekScan = (from s in aDb.Item_Scan_Event
        where
        s.item_detail_id == th_piece_id &&
        s.scan_type == scantype && (
        DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.scan_datetime.Value).Value == dt_scan.s.ScanDatetime.Date &&
        DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(s.scan_datetime.Value, dt_scan.s.ScanDatetime) == 0 )
        select s
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Update**

> 1. We could just use the `DiffMinutes` and that would work unless it was that exact same time and a different day ?

It will fail for the case when you have the same time span but different dates.

> 2. does `DiffMinutes` ignore the date portion ? So 11/11/2019 11:02 vs 11/12/2019 11:03 would be 1 ?

I'm not sure if it returns the diff between dates and time span or just time span, it has been a long time since I used it. I guess you'll test it and let us know.

Comment: Question:  Will that not chop off the minutes completely?
 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.scan_datetime.Value).Value -- ?

I like it, I am just trying to understand it.

Comment: I think I see, the first line verifes the date is the same and the second && condition looks to see if the difference in minutes exists?

Comment: so I guess I have two questions:
1. we could just use the DiffMinutes and that would work unless it was that exact same time and a different day?
2. does DiffMinutes ignore the date portion?  So 11/11/2019 11:02 vs 11/12/2019 11:03 would be 1?

Comment: @JoeRuder I edited my answer with details you asked for.

Comment: I work a Midnight to noon shift as part of my team is located in a different country than I am .
I will test it and let you know when I get back in......thank you

Comment: @JoeRuder glad I could help, please accept my answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but works.

```cs
//does this already exist?  Ignore items scanned within the same minute.
var seekScan = (from s in aDb.Item_Scan_Event
        where
        s.item_detail_id == th_piece_id &&
        s.scan_type == scantype &&
        (s.scan_datetime.Value.Year == dt_scan.s.ScanDatetime.Year &&
        s.scan_datetime.Value.Month == dt_scan.s.ScanDatetime.Month &&
        s.scan_datetime.Value.Day == dt_scan.s.ScanDatetime.Day &&
        s.scan_datetime.Value.Hour == dt_scan.s.ScanDatetime.Hour &&
        s.scan_datetime.Value.Minute == dt_scan.s.ScanDatetime.Minute )
        select s
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this [FUNCTION database.AddDays does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442260/function-database-adddays-does-not-exist)

In Mysql I've to create the function, perhabs you need to review the function in your bd.

Answer (score 1):

when you define a property of type Datetime if no attribute is defined for the property by default it will save the time including hour,minute and seconds as well.

so depending on the situation below are some usecases:

Scenario 1: check only for day/month/year

a) For DateTime

```
var loRecords = context.ORDERS.Where(x=>x.O_ORDER_TIME.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date).ToList()
```

b) For DateTime?

```
 var loRecords = context.ORDERS.Where(x=>x.O_ORDER_TIME?.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date).ToList()
```

Scenario 2: check for day/month/year Hour and minute

a) for DateTime

```
var loRecords = context.ORDERS.Where(x=>x.O_ORDER_TIME.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date) 
&& x.O_ORDER_TIME.Date.Hour == DateTime.Now.Date.Hour
&& x.O_ORDER_TIME.Date.Minute == DateTime.Now.Date.Minute).ToList()
```